# FullCalendar create event form / view event popup

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a react component of a form for creating a new event in FullCalendar? I don’t see one in the docs but it seems like an important piece of functionality.

Also, is there any standard popup component you can use to show details when a user clicks on an event?

Comment: No there isn't. I don't know the design decisions in full but I suspect it's deliberately left up to you, because people do this in all sorts of different ways, and often collect extra fields or have their own validation requirements etc. If you think it should be part of fullCalendar, ask the team: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features . It's open-source so of course you can offer to [contribute the code yourself](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing) too, if it gets accepted as a feature.